# Take xp machine off domain but keep accounts

Tags: windows-xp, domain, user-profiles

I recently had a domain controller go down at my company (small biz) and its going to be a while until we get it running again.

Is there a way to remove the domain from the laptops but still have the users keep their profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MS tools for account migration to copy the profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Why remove them from the domain? Let the laptops stay in the domain and users can log into them using their cached credentials.

There is no way for a local user to "keep" the profile of a previous domain user.

You are in for some hellish copy&pasting.

consult the links below for howtos

http://www.shofkom.com/2009/03/14/how-to-convert-your-domain-profile-to-a-local-profile/

http://mailman.mit.edu/pipermail/winpartners/2006-February/000333.html